# My mailer is not functioning, I have tried every means and I’m not that good with php

Tags: php, mailer

Please I need help with my php mailer code there is something I’m not doing correctly I was trying to add smtp to my php mailer but my code always show blank and white please help

I need help adding the smtp mailer code and from stoping my page from showing white each time smtp code is added.

I will appreciate any help provided thanks

```
    <?php


use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;

//Load composer's autoloader
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Host = 'smtp.mailtrap.io';
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = 'paste one generated by Mailtrap';
$mail->Password = 'paste one generated by Mailtrap’
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->Port = 2525;

  //send email    

// Turn this off when debugging and devloping
//error_reporting(0);

// Mail values
$fromName        =  trim($_POST["fromName"]);
$fromEmail       =  trim($_POST["fromEmail"]);
$toEmail         =  trim($_POST["toEmail"]);
$cc              =  trim($_POST["cc"]);
$bcc             =  trim($_POST["bcc"]);
$subjectLine     =  trim($_POST["subjectLine"]);

// Message Values
$richMessageText =  $_POST["richMessageText"];
$rawMessageText  =  $_POST["rawMessageText"];
$message         =  "";
$messageErrorSet = false;

// Attatchment
$path            = "uploads/";
$path            = $path . basename( $_FILES['attachment']['name']);
$fileTempName    = $_FILES['attachment']['tmp_name'];
$fileUploaded    = 0; // 0 = no upload, 1 = upload success, 2 = upload failure
$attatchError    = "";
    
// File attacher + error handler
if (!empty($fileTempName)) { //checks to see if a file was attatched
    // Attempt to upload file
    if(move_uploaded_file($fileTempName, $path)) {
        $fileUploaded = 1; // success
    } else {
        $fileUploaded = 2; // failure
        $attatchError = "Your message was not sent. There was an error uploading your attachment. Make sure that your php.ini file within your web server allows for file uploads, and that it allows for the upload size of your attatched file. Check out <a href='https://mediatemple.net/community/products/dv/204403894/how-can-i-edit-the-php.ini-file'>this guide</a> to make changes to the php.ini file.";
    }
}

// Store the right message body as the $message var
// If value exists for ritch text but not raw sore rich message text as $message
if(!empty($richMessageText) && empty($rawMessageText)) {
    $message = $richMessageText;
}
// If value exists for raw text but not ritch store raw message text as $message
elseif (empty($richMessageText) && !empty($rawMessageText)) {
    $message = $rawMessageText;
// If values exist for both then throw an error and update the error text
} elseif (!empty($richMessageText) && empty(!$rawMessageText)){
    $messageErrorText = "Your message was not sent. You have entered content into both the rich text editor and the raw text. Please return to the form and only use one.";
    $messageErrorSet = true;
} else {
    $messageErrorText = "Your message was not sent. It appears as if you did not enter any content into the message text area. Make sure that you go back and input content here.";
    $messageErrorSet = true;
}

  //send email

                 require_once "PHPMailer/PHPMailer.php";
              require_once 'PHPMailer/Exception.php';
              

// This code was brorrowed from the PHPMailer github page as an example useage
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);                              // Passing `true` enables exceptions
try {
    //Recipients
    $mail->setFrom($fromEmail, $fromName);
    $mail->addAddress($toEmail);
    // Add cc to header if there is a value in either
    if (!empty($cc)) {
        $mail->addCC($cc);
    }
    // Add bcc to header if there is a value
    if (!empty($bcc)) {
        $mail->addBCC($bcc);
    }
    //Attachments
    if (!empty($fileTempName)) {        //checks to see if a file was attatched
        $mail->addAttachment($path);    // Add attachments
    }
    //Content
    $mail->isHTML(true);                // Set email format to HTML
    $mail->Subject = $subjectLine;
    $mail->Body    = $message;

    // Send Mail using values
    if ($fileUploaded == 2) {
        //dont send message
    } else {
        $mail->send();
        //SUCESS mailed message
        echo "
        <div class=\"col-md-6 offset-md-3\">
            <div class=\"alert alert-success\" role=\"alert\">
                <strong>Email Sent!</strong> Email has been sent. Keep in mind that if you used the rich text editor, the message may appear slightly different in the actual email. Thanks for using Tramadol Xnet Spoofer!
            </div>
        </div>
        ";
    }

    // Failure message sent
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "
        <div class=\"col-md-6 offset-md-3\">
            <div class=\"alert alert-danger\" role=\"alert\">
                <p><strong>Awe Snap! </strong>Your message was not sent. Something went wrong with the PHP mail() function and is returning a value of FALSE. Chances are if you are seeing this message it means that it could not reach out to the SMTP server. Make sure that the webserver you are running is configured to also point to a mail server.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    ";
}

// SUCESS AND ERROR MESSAGES


// If message error is true display error
if ($messageErrorSet == true) {
    echo "
    <div class=\"col-md-6 offset-md-3\">
        <div class=\"alert alert-danger\" role=\"alert\">
            <p><strong>Awe Snap! </strong>".$messageErrorText."</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    ";
}
// If attat error
if ($fileUploaded == 2){
    echo "
    <div class=\"col-md-6 offset-md-3\">
        <div class=\"alert alert-danger\" role=\"alert\">
            <p><strong>Awe Snap! </strong>" . $attatchError . "</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    ";
}


?>
```

Comment: "white page" is not a valid debugging output. You have debugging functions. Why haven't you turned them on to see where in your code the problem starts? Have you verified where in the code flow the logic error is occurring? What troubleshooting *have* you done?

Comment: You might want to check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-can-i-get-useful-error-messages-in-php

Comment: Honestly speaking I haven’t done any troubleshooting

Comment: The error occurred when adding smtp code

Comment: If the smtp code is removed the page will be stable and working fine

Comment: The white page has to do with the smtp code I believe

Comment: This is the cause of the white page $mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Host = 'smtp.mailtrap.io';
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = 'paste one generated by Mailtrap';
$mail->Password = 'paste one generated by Mailtrap’
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->Port = 2525;

Comment: did you actually supply a password? or are you literally using `paste one generated by Mailtrap` ?

Comment: I am not using mailtrap I am using gmail smtp or webmail smtp

Comment: I have arranged the code the page is now showing but smtp not working I will past it on here

Comment: <?php

/**
 * This example shows making an SMTP connection with authentication.
 */

//Import the PHPMailer class into the global namespace
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;



  //send email    

// Turn this off when debugging and devloping
//error_reporting(0);

// Mail values
$fromName        =  trim($_POST["fromName"]);
$fromEmail       =  trim($_POST["fromEmail"]);
$toEmail         =  trim($_POST["toEmail"]);
$cc              =  trim($_POST["cc"]);
$bcc             =  trim($_POST["bcc"]);
$subjectLine     =  trim($_POST["subjectLine"]);

Comment: // Message Values
$richMessageText =  $_POST["richMessageText"];
$rawMessageText  =  $_POST["rawMessageText"];
$message         =  "";
$messageErrorSet = false;


// Attatchment
$path            = "uploads/";
$path            = $path . basename( $_FILES['attachment']['name']);
$fileTempName    = $_FILES['attachment']['tmp_name'];
$fileUploaded    = 0; // 0 = no upload, 1 = upload success, 2 = upload failure
$attatchError    = "";

Comment: // File attacher + error handler
if (!empty($fileTempName)) { //checks to see if a file was attatched

Comment: // Attempt to upload file
    if(move_uploaded_file($fileTempName, $path)) {
        $fileUploaded = 1; // success
    } else {
        $fileUploaded = 2; // failure
        $attatchError = "Your message was not sent. There was an error uploading your attachment. Make sure that your php.ini file within your web server allows for file uploads, and that it allows for the upload size of your attatched file. Check out <a href='https://mediatemple.net/community/products/dv/204403894/how-can-i-edit-the-php.ini-file'>this guide</a> to make changes to the php.ini file.";
    }

Comment: }

// Store the right message body as the $message var
// If value exists for ritch text but not raw sore rich message text as $message
if(!empty($richMessageText) && empty($rawMessageText)) {
    $message = $richMessageText;
}
// If value exists for raw text but not ritch store raw message text as $message
elseif (empty($richMessageText) && !empty($rawMessageText)) {
    $message = $rawMessageText;
// If values exist for both then throw an error and update the error text
}

Comment: elseif (!empty($richMessageText) && empty(!$rawMessageText)){
    $messageErrorText = "Your message was not sent. You have entered content into both the rich text editor and the raw text. Please return to the form and only use one.";
    $messageErrorSet = true;
} else {
    $messageErrorText = "Your message was not sent. It appears as if you did not enter any content into the message text area. Make sure that you go back and input content here.";
    $messageErrorSet = true;
}

Comment: /send email

                require_once "PHPMailer/PHPMailer.php";
require_once 'PHPMailer/Exception.php';          

// This code was brorrowed from the PHPMailer github page as an example useage
$mail = new PHPMailer(true); 

try {
   
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP(true);
$mail->Mailer = 'smtp';
$mail->Host = 'localhost';
$mail->Host = "mail.privateemail.com";
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->SMTPAutoTLS = true;
$mail->Port = 465;
$mail->Username = "lfreeman@onaccho.org";
$mail->Password = "yebshs"; // SMTP password

Comment: //Recipients
    $mail->setFrom($fromEmail, $fromName);
    $mail->addAddress($toEmail);
    // Add cc to header if there is a value in either
    if (!empty($cc)) {
        $mail->addCC($cc);
    }
    // Add bcc to header if there is a value
    if (!empty($bcc)) {
        $mail->addBCC($bcc);
    }
    //Attachments
    if (!empty($fileTempName)) {        //checks to see if a file was attatched
        $mail->addAttachment($path);    // Add attachments
    }

Comment: //Content
    $mail->isHTML(true);                // Set email format to HTML
    $mail->Subject = $subjectLine;
    $mail->Body    = $message;

    // Send Mail using values
    if ($fileUploaded == 2) {
        //dont send message
    } else {
        $mail->send();
        //SUCESS mailed message
        echo "
        <div class=\"col-md-6 offset-md-3\">

Comment: // Send Mail using values
    if ($fileUploaded == 2) {
        //dont send message
    } else {
        $mail->send();
        //SUCESS mailed message
        echo "
        <div class=\"col-md-6 offset-md-3\">
            <div class=\"alert alert-success\" role=\"alert\">
                <strong>Email Sent!</strong> Email has been sent. Keep in mind that if you used the rich text editor, the message may appear slightly different in the actual email!
            </div>
        </div>
        ";
    }

Comment: Failure message sent
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "
        <div class=\"col-md-6 offset-md-3\">
            <div class=\"alert alert-danger\" role=\"alert\">
                <p><strong>Awe Snap! </strong>Your message was not sent. Something went wrong with the PHP mail() function and is returning a value of FALSE. Chances are if you are seeing this message it means that it could not reach out to the SMTP server. Make sure that the webserver you are running is configured to also point to a mail server.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    ";

Comment: I have managed to fixed the code but the issue now is my mails are showing sent but nothing was delivered to my mailbox or spam box

Comment: Lol  incorrect password

Comment: Even my mail domain is not correct

Comment: I have fixed the problem, please does any one have any idea why the code above can’t spoof an email that doesn’t have DMARC?  Please share

Comment: The only problem is that it can’t spoof from address. Please help any help is appreciated

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: My php mailer is showing from my website when I used smtp please is there a way a header can be added for it not to show my website or mask my website please?